# AngularJS, how do I make the UI dependent on which field has focus?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS page with several form inputs.

When the some of the inputs have focus, I want to change other, arbitrary, aspects of the page.

For example, when the user is in the 'stock code' input, I want to display the list of popular stock codes.  When they are in the 'qty' field I want to show in-stock quantities and lead times.

Is there a variable which contains the 'current' input (the one which has focus), or do I need to revert to jQuery's onFocus.  (It seems a little primitive now.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about make a directive? You could set a variable whenever the user leaves/enters the input, and detect that:  http://jsfiddle.net/TZnj2/

Be sure to read the directive guide if you're confused as to what's happening: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Also I use scope.$apply in that directive, here's an explanation of what that does: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: So much of Angular JS seems elegant, this however seems like a lot of code to achieve this - did they forget ngFocus and ngBlur directives?

Comment: So you want elegant Try this on, then :-D:
http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/3Aevb/1/.  

And Angular just didn't want to write directives for _everything_, I guess. ng-click and ng-dblclick etc are just directives, yunno. Nothing special.

Comment: Just my opinion but I still think jQuery reads better in this particular blur/focus case (I over engineered this using an object,  could get away with less code if it were inlined) http://jsfiddle.net/gregk/r2336/

Comment: But then all of your logic is coupled to your DOM.  That's part of the angular's awesome.  The view cares about the DOM, the controller cares about the logic.

Comment: For a larger web application I'll concede that becomes an issue.

Comment: @Andy Joslin - that's a nice bit of code, but TZnj2 does exactly what I need.

Comment: @GregK, If you use directives smartly, then even bigger app will be manageable easily.

Answer (score 8):

[ngFocus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) and [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) are built-in directives:

```
<input ng-focus="hasFocus = true" ng-blur="hasFocus = false" type="text">
<p ng-show="hasFocus">The field has focus!!</p>
```

[Try demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqren/os4dr5dp/1/)