# how can i show a help message when the input is active, by using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, input

i have a input box needs help message. but it should only show when the input field is active. how can I do it by using angularjs? thanks.

```
<input id="MiddleName" class="form-control" type="text" value="" ng-model="model.MiddleName" name="MiddleName">
<p class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="????">this is middle name</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS, how do I make the UI dependent on which field has focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146792/angularjs-how-do-i-make-the-ui-dependent-on-which-field-has-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try it

```
<input id="MiddleName" 
ng-blur="showmsg = false" 
ng-focus="showmsg = true" 
class="form-control" type="text" 
value="" ng-model="model.MiddleName" 
name="MiddleName">
<p class="help-block ng-hide" 
ng-show="showmsg">this is middle name</p>
```

showmsg is true on focus, false on blur, and your div is showed if showmsg is true

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="">
<div>
<input name="aaa" ng-model="test" ng-focus="focussed = true" ng-blur="focussed = false"/>
<div ng-show="focussed"> This is focussed input</div>
```

I have used angular.js ver 1.2.1.
Hopefully this will help you.